# Unix - to filter find results by filename

Tags: bash, unix

In unix bash, I am getting files as result of find as follows:

```
find . -regextype posix-egrep -iregex "./[0-9]{8}/exp/RESULT.out"| sort

./20150128/exp/RESULT.out
./20150210/exp/RESULT.out
./20150218/exp/RESULT.out
./20150224/exp/RESULT.out
./20150318/exp/RESULT.out
./20150327/exp/RESULT.out
./20150330/exp/RESULT.out
```

Is it possible to filter this result by a date YYYYMMDD date string  so that I get only the files before and including a date specified ?

e.g. for 20150224, I only want to get

```
./20150128/exp/RESULT.out
./20150210/exp/RESULT.out
./20150218/exp/RESULT.out
./20150224/exp/RESULT.out
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `find` command:

```
export s='20150224'

find . -regextype posix-egrep -iregex "./[0-9]{8}/exp/RESULT.out" -exec \
     bash -c 'IFS=/ read -ra arr <<< "$1"; ((${arr[1]} <= s)) && echo "$1"' - '{}' \;
./20150128/exp/RESULT.out
./20150210/exp/RESULT.out
./20150218/exp/RESULT.out
./20150224/exp/RESULT.out
```

Comment: thanks anubahava..but what if I want to pass the string '20150224' as a variable ?..needless to say I new to unix.

Comment: I tried the newer option but the problem is that any historical file can be modified at the current date and then newer will give incorrect results

Comment: ok check my updated command, it will work the way you wanted. Instead of variable `s` you can pass any variable.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe the result through

```
awk -v FS=/ '$2<=20150224'
```

Comment: thx Vytenis for a compact solution...cannot upvote due to my new account